# Automatically and repeatedly execute a matlab script using the perl system function

Tags: matlab, perl, command-line, automation

The matlab script "NPBSS_CLR.m" can be found here https://github.com/NWPU-903PR/NPBSS_MATLAB. It can only process one input file at a time and requires the following input format:

```
>> NPBSS_CLR('file.fsa', '-n 1')
```

I have thousands of files to process and would like to do so automatically. First, I get ready to use matlab in the terminal.

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin 
./matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Then I try to run a Perl script I wrote for this job, but I get " syntax error near unexpected token `'file.fsa',' " errors. This type of error has been discussed a lot before, but it seems like each case is fairly unique and I am unable to correct this problem in my own code. It might be because of the way I am trying to use Perl in Matlab. If that is the case, how can I get Matlab to automatically process every file for me? I run the perl script like:

```
>> perl('Automate_NPBSS.pl')
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my @files = glob ('/Users/user/Desktop/NPBSS_MATLAB-master/*');
foreach my $file (@files){
    my $short_name = basename($file);
    if ($file =~ m/([TAGC]{20})(_\d+\.fsa)/){
        system(" NPBSS_CLR('$short_name', '-n 1') ");
    }
}
```

Examples of the specific errors:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `'TTCCACTGCGGAGCACCAGT_91.fsa','
sh: -c: line 0: `NPBSS_CLR('TTCCACTGCGGAGCACCAGT_91.fsa', '-n 1') '
```

Comment: Can't test right now but here's what I dig up from my history as terminal commands (don't start matlab first): `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r 'script(input)'`. Or `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -logfile ml_out.txt -r "script('input'); catch; end; quit"`.  These kinds of commands you can run from the terminal or out of another program, for example via `system` in Perl. The crucial bit is `-r`, so `matlab -r ...`.

Comment: @Emma, if you want to launch an interactive matlab session and then send commands to it, you might want to look into the [Expect module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect)

Comment: In my comment above, you'll also want to exit once the matlab script is done, so at the end of the first command: `... 'script(input)'; exit`.  You may also need to redirect the output altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this line:

```
system(" NPBSS_CLR('$short_name', '-n 1') ")
```

will end up calling something like this as a shell command:

```
NPBSS_CLR('TTCCACTGCGGAGCACCAGT_91.fsa', '-n 1')
```

There are two issues here:

- NPBSS_CLR is a Matlab function, not an OS-visible command you can call from the shell
- Parentheses (`(...)`) have special meaning to the shell

To run a Matlab function from Perl's `system(...)`, you need to have it launch Matlab to run that function using `matlab`'s `-r` option. Something like this:

```
system("/Applications/MATLAB_R2018a.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r \"NPBSS_CLR('$short_name', '-n 1'); exit\"");
```

The `.../matlab` invocation will get you running Matlab, and the escaped quotes (`\"...\"`) will "protect" the parentheses.

But if I were you, I would simplify this setup by removing the Perl script entirely and re-writing it as a Matlab M-code script that could call the `NPBSS_CLR` function directly. That way you don't have to worry about quoting your values to get through Perl and the shell, avoid the overhead of launching multiple Matlab sessions, and can work with everything in a single Matlab session's debugger. Something like this:

```
%Automate_NPBSS.m
function Automate_NPBSS

cd('/Users/user/Desktop/NPBSS_MATLAB-master/');
d = dir('*.fsa');
for i = 1:numel(d)
    file = d(i);
    if isempty(regexp(file.name, '[TAGC]{20}_\d+\.fsa'))
        continue
    end
    NPBSS_CLR(file.name, '-n 1');
end
end
```

(Only caveat is that you won't be able to easily parallelize this without the Matlab Parallel Computing toolbox, so if you want to do that, you'll need to stick with `system()` in Perl or Matlab.)